# traincascade, classifiers and openCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision

Currently, I'm training some data and I'm in the eleventh stage. However, I've been sitting here most of the day without moving to the 12th stage. Stages 1-10 took less than 18 hours to complete and my acceptanceRatio is approaching almost 10^-7 low. I was wondering if there was a good way to force complete the classifier xml file based off of the data I've currently trained. Or If I can stop the process and then generate a classifier based off of the stages I've attained at this point. How can I go about this?

Also, I was wondering what an ideal acceptance ratio was. I'm assuming it's a small number at this point but if anyone can help clear that up that would be awesome.

for reference, these are the parameters I'm using for the train:

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: classifier
vecFileName: samples.vec
bgFileName: negatives.txt
numPos: 68
numNeg: 436
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 3072
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 3072
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 80
sampleHeight: 80
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.999
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: ALL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can stop it at, say, stage 15.

for testing with the working 14 stages(15 might be broken), you re-send your cmdline with num_stages 14. this will generate a cascade.xml you can use.

later just restart with num_cascades 30 to finish the training. (maybe you have to *delete* stage 15)